# File got corrupted when I Read the file's all bytes on list type of object then write a file again Using c#

Tags: c#

I've lot of tried to write file from collection of bytes. but file always get corrupted. not sure why its happening. If somebody knows about it would be helpful me more.

Note: Its always working good when I uncomment under while loop this line //AppendAllBytes(pathSource, bytes);

but I need bytes from object. later on I will use this concept on p2p.

```
namespace Sender
{
    static class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
                      string pathSource = "../../Ok&SkipButtonForWelcomeToJakayaWindow.jpg";
            using (FileStream fsSource = new FileStream(pathSource,
                     FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
            {
                // Read the source file into a byte array.
                const int numBytesToRead = 100000; // Your amount to read at a time
                byte[] bytes = new byte[numBytesToRead];
                int numBytesRead = 0;
                if (File.Exists(pathSource))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("File of this name already exist, you want to continue?");
                    System.IO.FileInfo obj = new System.IO.FileInfo(pathSource);
                    pathSource = "../../Files/" + Guid.NewGuid() + obj.Extension;
                }

                int i = 0;
                byte[] objBytes = new byte[numBytesRead];
                List<FileInfo> objFileInfo = new List<FileInfo>();
                Guid fileID = Guid.NewGuid();
                FileInfo fileInfo = null;
                while (numBytesToRead > 0)
                {
                    // Read may return anything from 0 to numBytesToRead.
                    int n = fsSource.Read(bytes, numBytesRead, numBytesToRead);
                    i++;
                    //AppendAllBytes(pathSource, bytes);
                    fileInfo = new FileInfo { FileID = fileID, FileBytes = bytes, FileByteID = i };
                    objFileInfo.Add(fileInfo);
                    // Break when the end of the file is reached.
                    if (n == 0)
                    {
                        break;
                    }
                    // Do here what you want to do with the bytes read (convert to string using Encoding.YourEncoding.GetString())
                }
                //foreach (var b in objFileInfo.OrderBy(m => m.FileByteID))
                //{
                //    AppendAllBytes(pathSource, b.FileBytes);
                //}


                foreach (var item in objFileInfo)
                {
                    AppendAllBytes(pathSource, item.FileBytes);
                }
                fileInfo = null;
            }
        }
        static void AppendAllBytes(string path, byte[] bytes)
        {
            using (var stream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Append))
            {
                stream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
            }
        }
    }
    class FileInfo
    {
        public Guid FileID { get; set; }
        public int FileByteID { get; set; }
        public byte[] FileBytes { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you looking for File.Copy? What do you mean with "corrupt"? Can you try with a text file of numBytesToRead + 1 bytes, with a small value of numBytesToRead so you can debug this code yourself?

Comment: @CodeCaster with text file its working fine. I'm getting problem on another extension.

Comment: You missed the part where I asked to test with a text file that is larger than numBytesRead.

Comment: @CodeCaster i'm facing problem always when the file bytes is larger than numBytesRead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is two problem in your code :

1. The block of data is all of size `100000`, which cannot work most of time unless the file size is exactly a multiple of it. So, the last block of data will contains 0s.
2. `FileInfo.FileBytes` will change, if you change the buffer to something new causing the every single block of data being the identical to the last block read.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;

static class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string pathSource = "test.jpg";


        using (FileStream fsSource = new FileStream(pathSource, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
        {
            // Read the source file into a byte array.
            const int BufferSize = 100000; // Your amount to read at a time
            byte[] buffer = new byte[BufferSize];

            if (File.Exists(pathSource))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("File of this name already exist, you want to continue?");
                System.IO.FileInfo obj = new System.IO.FileInfo(pathSource);
                pathSource = "Files/" + Guid.NewGuid() + obj.Extension;
            }

            int i = 0, offset = 0, bytesRead;
            List<FileInfo> objFileInfo = new List<FileInfo>();
            Guid fileID = Guid.NewGuid();

            while (0 != (bytesRead = fsSource.Read(buffer, offset, BufferSize)))
            {
                var data = new byte[bytesRead];
                Array.Copy(buffer, data, bytesRead);

                objFileInfo.Add(new FileInfo { FileID = fileID, FileBytes = data, FileByteID = ++i });
            }

            foreach (var item in objFileInfo)
            {
                AppendAllBytes(pathSource, item.FileBytes);
            }
        }
    }

    static void AppendAllBytes(string path, byte[] bytes)
    {
        using (var stream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Append))
        {
            stream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
        }
    }
}

class FileInfo
{
    public Guid FileID { get; set; }
    public int FileByteID { get; set; }
    public byte[] FileBytes { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Thanks you so much man. Its working fine now. again thankful to you

Answer (score 1):

You don't increase numBytesRead and don't decrease numBytesToRead.

Comment: Its always working good when I uncomment under while loop this line //AppendAllBytes(pathSource, bytes);

Comment: It's not surprising you don't get a corrupt file when you don't write to a file. Please test as I said, put breakpoints in your code, step through it and inspect your variables. The code reading the file is not doing what you expect it to.

Answer (score 1):

objFileInfo contains a List of `FileInfo` which contains a **reference type** `byte[]`.

You copy the reference to the bytes when you create a new `FileInfo` and then repeatedly overwrite those bytes until you reach the end of the file.

```
            byte[] bytes = new byte[numBytesToRead];
            //...
            List<FileInfo> objFileInfo = new List<FileInfo>();
            //...
            //...
            while (numBytesToRead > 0)
            {
                int n = fsSource.Read(bytes, numBytesRead, numBytesToRead);
                //First time here bytes[0] == the first byte of the file
                //Second time here bytes[0] == 10000th byte of file
                //...
                //The following line should copy the bytes into file info instead of the reference to the existing byte array
                fileInfo = new FileInfo { ..., FileBytes = bytes, ... };
                objFileInfo.Add(fileInfo);
                //First time here objFileInfo[0].FileBytes[0] == first byte of file
                //Second time here objFileInfo[0].FileBytes[0] == 10000th byte of file because objFileInfo[All].FileBytes == bytes
                //...
            }
```

You can test this by looking in the `FileBytes` variable for multiple `FileInfo`. I'd bet the contents look similar

Comment: You copy the reference to the bytes when you create a new FileInfo and then repeatedly overwrite those bytes until you reach the end of the file.

Could you pls give me code ?

Comment: @user3678531 I've added the relevant parts of your own code which lead to the error. Hopefully you can see where you have gone wrong.